# Why my symfony captcha always return valid?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, recaptcha, captcha

I followed [this tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1060/how-to-implement-botdetect-captcha-in-your-symfony-4-forms) to add a captcha to my form.

First I install it using

```
composer require captcha-com/symfony-captcha-bundle:"4.*"
```

After I Install it, I got an error on a file called `captcha.html.twig`
Error:

> captcha Unexpected "spaceless" tag (expecting closing tag for the
> "block" tag defined near line 2).

So I changed `{% spaceless  %}`  to  `{% apply spaceless  %}`
And the error is gone.

But My captcha bot always returns True (even when I don't even fill it.
Here is the `->add()` function of my form:

```
->add('captchaCode', CaptchaType::class, [
    'captchaConfig' => 'ExampleCaptchaUserRegistration',
    'constraints' => [
        new ValidCaptcha([
            'message' => 'Invalid captcha, please try again',
        ]),
    ],]);
```

Code of Routes.yaml :

```
captcha_routing:
    resource: "@CaptchaBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Code of captcha.php :

```
<?php 
// app/config/packages/captcha.php
if (!class_exists('CaptchaConfiguration')) { return; }

// BotDetect PHP Captcha configuration options
return [
    // Captcha configuration for example form
    'ExampleCaptchaUserRegistration' => [
        'UserInputID' => 'captchaCode',
        'ImageWidth' => 250,
        'ImageHeight' => 50,
    ],
];
```

Captcha field on the `User.php` entity:

```
protected $captchaCode;

public function getCaptchaCode()
{
  return $this->captchaCode;
}

public function setCaptchaCode($captchaCode)
{
  $this->captchaCode = $captchaCode;
}
```

Code in the View (twig)

```
<span class="txt1 p-b-11">
    Are You a Robot?
</span>
<div class="wrap-input100 m-b-36">
    {{ form_widget(form.captchaCode, {'attr': {'class': 'input100'} }) }}       
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
<div class="error">{{ form_errors(form.captchaCode) }} </div>
```

Controlleur function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="user_register", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function register(Request $request,UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, ['validation_groups' => ['register'], ]);
    $form ->remove("description");
    $form ->remove("phone");
    $form ->remove("website");
    $form ->remove("facebook");
    $form ->remove("picture");

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $hash = $encoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getPassword());
        $user->setPassword($hash);

        // defaults values (user can edit them later)
        $user->setDescription("Apparently, this User prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.");
        $user->setPhone(null);
        $user->setPicture("default.png");
        $user->setWebsite(null);
        $user->setFacebook(null);
        $user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);
        // end default values
    
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_login');
}
    return $this->render('authentication/register.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the controller action where you handle the request?

Comment: @ArleighHix done! I added the controller code.